Find all ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_n$ to $\Bbb Z $
Find all ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_n$ to  $\Bbb Z$
This was past an exam test and there was no answer given from the professor.I need some help how can I approach such problems.
If I let $\Phi\colon \Bbb Z_n\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $\Phi([x]_n)=  x$ and show that
$$\Phi([x+y]_n)=\Phi([x]_n)+\Phi([y]_n)$$ and
$$\Phi([xy]_n)=\Phi([x]_n)\Phi([y]_n)$$
will this be enough?
Also how do we know that there are not any other homomorphisms?
Thank you.

Let $n=7$.  How do you define $\Phi([9]_7)$?  If the answer is $[2]_7$, then what is $\Phi ([5]_7+[4]_7)$?

I assume $\mathbb{Z}n$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ not $\lim{\longleftarrow} \mathbb{Z}/n^e\mathbb{Z}$. What does $\Phi([x]_n)=x$ mean? This is ill-defined, because $[x]_n = [x+n]_n$. Also, do ring homomorphisms preserve identity, like $\Phi(1_n) = 1$? Then $\Phi(n_n) = n = 0$?

The title of the proposed dupe is somewhat misleading as it also includes the case of the OP.

Your map is not well-defined. Actually the zero-homomorphism is the only group homomorphism $\mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb Z$ and hence also the only ring homomorphism.
To see this, let $f : \mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb Z$ be group homomorphism. Let $a = f([1])$. Since $[1] + \ldots +[1] = [0]$ (sum with $n$ summands), we get
$$na =a + \ldots + a = f([1] + \ldots +[1]) = f([0]) = 0 .$$
Therefore $a = 0$. This implies $f = 0$.

So in general,if we show that the zero-homomorphism is the only group homomorphism  this implies that is the only ring homomorphism?

@Manyquestions Yes. Each ring homomorphism is a  group homomorphism, hence if $0$  is the only group homomorphism, then it must be the only ring homomorphism .
